# Two tag questions

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Here are two simple tag questions:

1. Do we really do the tag [white](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/white)? I think we can get rid of it as it serves no current function.
2. Should [formation](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formation) be a synonym of [patterns](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patterns)? They seem very similar to me. If there **is** a difference, the descriptions should be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right, [white](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/white) isn't really useful. Almost all questions on the site involve White (and Black). It might make some sense to group all questions focusing on an opening repertoire for white, but we're not going to retag all those questions. So the best option (to me) seems to be to [burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/295232) it.

Looking at the [patterns](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patterns) tag description, it's a subset of [tactics](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tactics), but a few questions ([Why is it common to castle right after the opponent castles?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/19462/7297), [Looking for information on PARADISE (software)](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/7877/7297)) are not. Formation makes me think of a *pawn* formation, but we already have [pawn-stucture](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pawn-stucture) for that. Perhaps [Is Colle-Zukertort a good way to improve beginner play?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/274/7297) and [What are the advantages of the Stonewall attack?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/339/7297) can be retagged to use that one. If we then drop the [formation](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formation) tag from [Full "reverse checkers" position in GM game with 12 or more pieces per player?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/28034/7297), it'll be gone.